# Does a UK visa have anything to do with getting a US visit visa?

Tags: visas, usa, uk

I want to know is there anything like this: if the UK grants you a visa, then the USA will not issue a visa to you. I have valid 6-month UK visitor visa and travelled there for 9 days. Now I want to apply for a US visa at the beginning of next year. Can I do that?

Comment: What made you think so? Totally false

Comment: someone told me like this . I was really upset how is this possible . even its plus point if you have UK visa or you visited on it .

Comment: There’s no direct correlation between being granted a U.K. visa and a decision on a US visa application. Gaining the former may help with getting the latter, but you’d still need to make a strong application including overcoming the US assumption of immigrant intent. AFAIK the UK does not openly start from that assumption, although it does place great emphasis on a potential visitor’s intention to leave and ability to support themselves during their trip. Will you have used your UK visa before applying to the US?

Comment: Yes i have traveled in London for 9 days .

Comment: Other way around: if the UK **would have refused** your visa request, it would be a negative for your US visa request.

Comment: Note that in many cases, you can only apply for a visa at the embassy/consulate that serves your place of residence. So you would need to return to your place of residence to apply, you wouldn’t be able to apply at the US embassy in London (TBC, I haven’t checked whether the US embassy in London has this kind of policy).

Comment: @jcaron the US explicitly disclaims such a policy, but notes that an embassy or consulate other than the place of residence might have difficulty assessing a visa applicant (presumably because of unfamiliarity with the local law in the place of residence, among other reasons).  See https://travel.state.gov/content/travel/en/us-visas/tourism-visit/visitor.html ("You may schedule your interview at another U.S. Embassy or Consulate, but be aware that it may be more difficult to qualify for a visa outside of the country where you live.")

Comment: @jcaron yes buddy i am already in Doha '' where I am doing my job. definately i will apply from here . im living here with my family.

Answer (score 6):

Having a UK visa in no way disqualifies you from getting a US visa. The US and UK are very close allies.

Comment: Quite right. It's very likely the OP heard somewhere that REFUSAL of one can affect the other.

Comment: And even then, it just raises the *likelihood* of a refusal. The UK and the USA are both fully sovereign and have the authority to make their own decisions.

Answer (score -2):

False. But if you are asking for experiences, I got my US visa in 2014 successfully and my passport had a UK visa stamped from 2011. This should make you feel better.